# Is there way to show only line without area in Google charts stacked line area chart with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-visualization

I am adding three different data arrays in one chart, and one of the data sets is transparent. I would like for that data set just to have the line rather than having whole area colored.
[Transparent Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXpSJ.png)

[Colored Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dX3O.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had to set lineWidth of top data to 0
[Code for line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhQma.png)

[Result, only midle data has line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJy18.png)

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual code. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help